# Sylvester’s determinant theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I need some help to prove the following [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spkxQ.png):

$log\,|\sigma^2\cdot I_N+\varPhi_N^T\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot\varPhi_N|=(N-n)\cdot log\,\sigma^2+log\,|P(\alpha)|+log\,|\sigma^2\cdot P(\alpha)^{-1}+\varPhi_N\cdot\varPhi_N^T|$

The matrix $\varPhi_N$  has dimension $n \times N$ while the matrix $P(\alpha)$ has dimensions $n \times n$ and is positive (semi?)-definite. The variable $\sigma^2$ has dimension $1 \times 1$ (non-negative scalar: $\sigma^2\ge0$).

Any help to tackle the above simplification is welcome. Thank you

What I tried so far:
$(N-n)\cdot log\,\sigma^2+log\,|P(\alpha)|+log\,|\sigma^2\cdot P(\alpha)^{-1}+\varPhi_N\cdot\varPhi_N^T|=log(|\sigma^2\cdot I_{N-n}|\cdot |P(\alpha)|\cdot |\sigma^2\cdot P(\alpha)^{-1}+\varPhi_N\cdot\varPhi_N^T|)=log\,|\sigma^2\cdot I_N+\varPhi_N^T\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot\varPhi_N|$

$\implies$

$|\sigma^2\cdot I_{N-n}|\cdot |P(\alpha)|\cdot |\sigma^2\cdot P(\alpha)^{-1}+\varPhi_N\cdot\varPhi_N^T|=|\sigma^2\cdot I_N+\varPhi_N^T\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot\varPhi_N|$

$|\sigma^2\cdot I_{N-n}|\cdot |\sigma^2 \cdot P(\alpha)\cdot P(\alpha)^{-1}+P(\alpha)\cdot \varPhi_N\cdot\varPhi_N^T|=|\sigma^2\cdot I_N+\varPhi_N^T\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot\varPhi_N|$

$|\sigma^2\cdot I_{N-n}|\cdot |\sigma^2 \cdot I_n+P(\alpha)\cdot \varPhi_N\cdot\varPhi_N^T|=|\sigma^2\cdot I_N+\varPhi_N^T\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot\varPhi_N|$

$\sigma^{2\cdot(N-n)} \cdot \sigma^{2\cdot n}\cdot|I_n+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot \varPhi_N\cdot\varPhi_N^T|=\sigma^{2\cdot N}\cdot|I_N+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\cdot\varPhi_N^T\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot\varPhi_N|$

$\sigma^{2\cdot N} |I_n+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot \varPhi_N\cdot\varPhi_N^T|=\sigma^{2\cdot N}\cdot|I_N+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\cdot\varPhi_N^T\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot\varPhi_N|$

$|I_n+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot \varPhi_N\cdot\varPhi_N^T|=|I_N+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\cdot\varPhi_N^T\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot\varPhi_N|$

let $A=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\cdot P(\alpha)\cdot \varPhi_N$ and $B=\varPhi_N^T$

we have the Sylvester’s determinant theorem:

$|I_n+A \cdot B|=|I_N+B \cdot A|$

Comment: Write your formula as a relationship between product of determinants, and recognize a version of Schur (complement) determinant formula https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/some-notes-on-the-schur-complement/.

Comment: @JeanMarie I tried without success

Comment: @JeanMarie Maybe I proved it, can you check please?

Comment: I have checked: it's a good proof! Please note that the hypothesis about semi definite positiveness of $P(\alpha )$ isn't used. But, on the other hand, you have used the fact that $P(\alpha )$ is invertible, which hopefuly isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my question with the answer